# Compile Element in Parent Scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got two directives. The first `mark-required` goes through all elements in checks if they are required, if so it adds a* and some css etc.

The second `flexible-required` makes an input field dynamically required, I need it because diff. user inputs have diff. required fields.

I get the second directive working with `compile` but the directives from the parent scope e.g. `mark-required` do get ignored.

### Directive `flexible-required`

```
angular.module 'tsd.flexibleRequired', ['ui.bootstrap.showErrors']
  .directive 'flexibleRequired', ($http, $rootScope, implantsService) ->
    return {
      restrict: 'A'
      scope:
        isRequired: '='
      controller: ($scope, $element, $compile) ->
        compileElement = $element[0]
        # compileForm = angular.element(document).find('form')[0] #B
        $scope.$watch('isRequired', (newValue, oldValue)->
          if newValue != oldValue
            if newValue == true
              compileElement.required = true
            else
              compileElement.required = false

            $compile(compileElement)($scope) #A
            # $compile(compileForm)($scope.$parent) #B
        )
        return
    }
```

- A: If I add `$scope.$parent`in that spot nothing happens
- B: If I do uncomment the lines below, it does work, but all my inputs get compiled, I only want to have this specific element compiled in my parent scope.

### HTML

```
<form name="patientDataForm" ng-submit="save()" mark-required>
...
          <div class="form-group col-lg-6" show-errors>
            <label>Versicherungsnummer/Krankenkasse</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="insurance" ng-model="registerPatientController.patientData.insurance" placeholder="Versicherungsnummer oder Krankenkasse" ng-pattern="/^[0-9].*$/" is-required="registerPatientController.patientData.sendToEprd"flexible-required enter-to-tab/>
            <p class="help-block" ng-if="patientDataForm.insurance.$error">Ihre Versicherungsnummer/Krankenkasse wird benötigt!</p>
          </div>
```

### Question:

How can I only compile `compileElement` in the parent scope?

Comment: Edit: my current solution is to broadcast in `flexible-required` and to listen in `mark-required` and call the functions manually. In this case this is Ok but it would be interesting to see a diff. solution for other cases.